# How to fix index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a udemy course with Rails and I've also tried following the guidance in "[Getting Started with Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)",
but no matter what my application can't locate my template files.

app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# The welcome controller.
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index; end
end
```

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Show the errors on the console and on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line get 'welcome/index' 
OR simply change it to
get 'welcome/index', to: 'welcome#index'
Hopefully this would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what the issue was. My mounted drive was called "HDD (Mint)" changing it to "HDD-Mint" and now it's working perfectly!